# Could not connect to the AMQP server via Docker container

Tags: docker, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to use [Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) with the AMQP Transport within my Dockerized Symfony application. When I dispatch a message in the handler, I get the following error:

```
In AmqpReceiver.php line 62:

  [Symfony\Component\Messenger\Exception\TransportException]
  Could not connect to the AMQP server. Please verify the provided DSN.
```

messenger.yaml:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Message\MyCustomRequest': async
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - 5671:5672
      - 15671:15672
```

.env:

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/%2f/messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the environment variable to

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@host.docker.internal:5672/%2f/messages
```

Seems to do the trick

Comment: Then you are trying to connect to the HOST IP.. `host.docker.internal` is resolving your host ip, you are not connecting to your docker instance anymore!?